# I get poor image quality when generating images with GD

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I get poor image quality when trying to generate image using PHP GD. Here is the code http://paste2.org/p/1220178 I use it to convert a bunch of files into a merged/thumb images file.

Comment: was wondering maybe I was doing something wrong, of possibly there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://www.php.net/imagecopyresampled) instead of [`imagecopyresized()`](http://www.php.net/imagecopyresized).